# Android Showcase View how to use to one show?

Tags: java, android, showcaseview

How can I display the Tab Target only once when opening the activity for the first time?
This is my code :

```
textView = findViewById(R.id.main_title_activity_text);

    new TapTargetSequence(this)
            .targets(
                    TapTarget.forView(textView,"Button 1","This is Button 1")
                            .outerCircleColor(R.color.orange)
                            .outerCircleAlpha(0.96f)
                            .targetCircleColor(R.color.white)
                            .titleTextSize(20)
                            .titleTextColor(R.color.white)
                            .descriptionTextSize(10)
                            .descriptionTextColor(R.color.black)
                            .textColor(R.color.black)
                            .textTypeface(Typeface.SANS_SERIF)
                            .dimColor(R.color.black)
                            .drawShadow(true)
                            .cancelable(false)
                            .tintTarget(true)
                            .transparentTarget(true)
                            .targetRadius(60)
                   
            );
```

Comment: Keep some boolean check before show  it. Keep a flag like is "tabTargetShown=false" after  you have shown it once make this flag true

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I'm a very beginner, I really don't know how to apply your answer, please can you explain with an example?

Comment: Can you share you Activity/Fragment where you have called Tab Target  ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, do you mean I send the complete code for the activity in which the id is located following the text?

Comment: Yes,  please share the Complete Activity code, so that  I can see where these checks need  to  be  applied

Comment: I tried to send the code, but it was not accepted because it was too long

Comment: Just send the  method where you are calling Tab Target

Comment: @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

Comment: Please send  the complete  code of onCreate() method

Comment: @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test_everything);

        TapTargetView.showFor(this,
                TapTarget.forView(findViewById(R.id.text_1), "This is a target", "We have the best targets, believe me")
                        .outerCircleColor(R.color.dark_blue)
                        .outerCircleAlpha(0.96f)
                        .targetCircleColor(R.color.white)
                        .titleTextSize(20)
                        .titleTextColor(R.color.white)

Comment: It does not contain anything else, it only contains visible text (for testing)

Comment: Please check this my question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73778399/open-taptargetsequence-only-on-first-use-of-application

Answer (score 0):

//If you have your  sharedPreferecne class  use that or else  use below

```
 public class SharedPref {
 private static SharedPreferences mSharedPref;
 public static final String IS_SHOWN = "IS_SHOWN";

 private SharedPref() {
 }

 public static void init(Context context) {
    if (mSharedPref == null)
        mSharedPref = 
 context.getSharedPreferences(context.getPackageName(), 
Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
}


public static boolean read(String key, boolean defValue) {
    return mSharedPref.getBoolean(key, defValue);
}

public static void write(String key, boolean value) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = mSharedPref.edit();
    prefsEditor.putBoolean(key, value);
    prefsEditor.commit();
 }

}

 //Put  this code in onCreate
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    SharedPref.init(getApplicationContext());

    if (!SharedPref.read(SharedPref.IS_SHOWN, false)) {
        SharedPref.write(SharedPref.IS_SHOWN, true);
        TapTargetView.showFor(this, 
  TapTarget.forView(findViewById(R.id.text_1)
                                , "This is a target", "We have the best 
 targets, believe me")
                        
 .outerCircleColor(R.color.dark_blue).outerCircleAlpha(0.96f)
                        
  .targetCircleColor(R.color.white).titleTextSize(20)
                        .titleTextColor(R.color.white);

    }
}
```